# How to install 32 bit Java 8 version specific update 171 in Ubuntu machine using Putty

Tags: linux, ubuntu-18.04

I have Linux Ubuntu/debian-bash machine with Java 64 bit installed and my client needs 32 bit Java 8 version as well with 171 update only because its a free version and later 171 update it required licence.So could you please help with installation with the required version Java 8 32 bit update 171.I am only accessible through Putty.So please guide me with commands or any other approach and its highly appreciated if you could help on this.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can also use openJDK for free

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

Comment: will that command install java 8 update 171 version. Because I need the exact version to be installed in that prod machine and that too it should be a 32 bit version . So please help me on this.

Comment: Thanks for the links but it will install Java 8 with latest updates but I need Java 8 with update 171 only since client needed this particular update to be installed and it should be 32 bit version. Could you please help on this so that it will be most helpful ?

Comment: Well, then the only way is to go to oracle website https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html and download the rpm file

Comment: I downloaded rpm file and tar.gz file in ubuntu machine and now when I run tar zxvf  jdk-8u171-linux-x64.tar.gz it is extracting the files and after that I have run the below commands to export java path like export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_171 and export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin and ran java -version but it is showing the already existed version but not the 171 version which I extracted and set path.

Comment: Did I wrongly updated java_home or path variable wrongly or do I need to update anywhere? Kindly suggest me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215664/discussion-between-pdbr-praveen-and-matthias-reissner).